# Swift value type did not copy on first assignment?

Tags: swift, value-type

The example in official document explain value type as this that the copy operation will occurred in assignment:

```
// Value type example
struct S { var data: Int = -1 }
var a = S()
var b = a                       // a is copied to b
a.data = 42                     // Changes a, not b
```

I have a question in the line

```
var a = S()
```

This line is also a assignment ,But from the code comment this line seems will not make a copy operation.

**Is this line will also cause a copy operation or not?** ( e.g: system malloc a S() in memory address C, and then copy to another address B, and the var a will point to this address B )?

Comment: You are calling a constructor that _creates_ an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't cause a copy operation. Since this is a `struct` there is no need for a malloc (or it's Swift equivalent `swift_allocObject`). It will just allocate an Int size from the stack by changing stack pointer.

See the godbolt [here](https://swift.godbolt.org/z/MWvv7P7zh)

Answer (score 1):

The line `var a = S()` will assign the variable named `a` to a new instance of struct S. Therefore, there is not any copy here. If S was of type class, this would not change anything: no copy. With a `let` assignment instead of `var`, there would be no copy. This is a direct assignment of a new instance to a new variable name.

**Remember that when dealing with a struct object, like with any value type object, swift makes a copy only to avoid having two references to the same object.** The line `var a = S()` does not create more than one reference to the object, therefore there is no need to copy anything.